# LaTeX/MathJax does not render in some question thumbnail

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax, frontpage

Sometimes I have [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025361/verifying-a-limit-with-lambert-w-function) thumbnail that does not render LaTeX:

[image]

I have compared my code with other posts, I do not found differences that can explain this behavior.

What can cause LaTeX or MathJax not to render in thumbnails?

Comment: The $\rm\LaTeX$ is not complete in the excerpt generating the thumbnail, and thus does not compile.

Comment: Thank you for being reactive. I am sorry I do not understand what you meant? What LaTeX is not complete? I have no LaTeX error within the post itself.

Comment: The thumbnail is generated by clipping some part of the question. This clipping does not contain the entire $\rm\LaTeX$ code, and therefore does not compile.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thus having a long LaTeX code at the beginning of the post lead to cropped LaTeX and does not render. Thank you it is clear now. I you mind making it an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thumbnail is generated by cropping part of your question. Since the $\rm\LaTeX$ is not fully within that cropped part, the code does not compile.

One could argue in favor of changing the code of the excerpt generator to always complete the $\rm\LaTeX$ code if the crop happens halfway through it, but this opens up a few different problems. For example people using `align` environment or other multiline environment that would end up taking far more display real estate than originally intended.

Comment: I will not argue about this, I am glad to understand how I could circonvolve the "issue". Thank you for making it an answer.